# Numbers $n$ whose representation as the product of two divisors require more digits than that of $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

**Note**: [Posted to MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417062/numbers-n-whose-representation-as-the-product-of-two-divisors-require-more-dig) since it is unanswered in MSE.

Let $f(x)$ be the number of digits in the decimal representation of $x$ e.g. $, f(0) = 1, f(1729) = 4$. If $n = ab$ then we can show that $f(ab) > f(a) + f(b)$ is impossible. Hence $f(ab)$ is either less than or equal to $f(a) + f(b)$. Loosely speaking if $f(ab) < f(a) + f(b)$, we are using more digits than the number itself hence we are wasting digits.

**Definition**: A number $n$ is said to be a wasteful number if for all its divisors $n = ab$, we have $f(ab) < f(a) + f(b)$.

E.g. The divisors of $4321$ are $[1, 29, 149, 4321]$ and clearly $4321$ is wasteful. But $4324$ is not a wasteful number since $4324 = 46 \times 94$ and $f(4324) = f(46) + f(94) = 4$. Trivially, all primes $p$ are wasteful since $f(p \times 1) < f(p) + f(1)$. The first few wasteful numbers are:

$$
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17, 19, 22, 23, 26, 29, 31, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 50, 51, 52, 53, 55, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99
$$

**Update**: Added graph for the density of wasteful numbers below $10^9$. There are $386000005$ wasteful numbers below $10^9$.

[image]

**Question 1**: Does the natural density of wasteful numbers exist? Experimental data for $n \le 10^9$ suggests that it oscillates in a regular pattern between $0.2$ and $0.4$.

**Question 2**: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a number to be wasteful?

**Update**: 7 Apr 2023
It was [proved in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417062/numbers-n-whose-representation-as-the-product-of-two-divisors-require-more-dig?_gl=1*a5tzhk*_ga*MTM2NjQwODQ3My4xNjgwNjgxNjk2*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4MDg1MDU3NC4xMC4xLjE2ODA4NTQ3NjAuMC4wLjA.) that

> Every wasteful number n must be its own lexicographically greatest
> divisor

Comment: Why are all primes wasteful?  If $n=p$ is a prime, then the only factoring of $p$ to consider is $p=p\times 1$, but then $f(p)=f(p\times 1)<f(p)+f(1)=f(p)+1$.  Did you mean to exclude $1$ as a factor or something like that?

Comment: I think you have your inequalities the wrong way round, Nilotpal. $3=f(144)<f(12)+f(12)=2+2=4$, so $f(ab)<f(a)+f(b)$ is certainly possible. It's $f(ab)>f(a)+f(b)$ that's impossible.

Comment: Whatever definition you intended (certainly not what you wrote), the sequence of numbers you wrote down appears to be [A122427](http://oeis.org/A122427)

Comment: @lulu, it does match that sequence as far as OP has calculated it, but the definitions are different. I'm not convinced that it's the same sequence.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  Neither am I , but that's a pretty long list for a coincidental match.  Of course, both lists contain the primes so the "coincidence" only concerns the composites.  And both lists expressly concern the decimal representations of the integers and their factors, so...maybe?

Comment: We have $f(x)=\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor+1$. Assuming the "unused fractional digit amounts" $f(x)-\log_{10}x$ are i.i.d. among a number and its divisors should yield an estimate for the density.

Comment: @Karl: nope, $f(x)=\lfloor\log_{10}x\rfloor+1$.

Comment: Oops, fixed. In any case, I propose viewing each way of writing $n=ab$ as a random opportunity to "use digits efficiently enough" to make $n$ non-wasteful.

Comment: @lulu Added the list of wasteful numbers $\le 100$ and it still matches A122427. Doesn't look like a coincidence anymore.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Typpo in the inequality corrected. Thanks!

Comment: You have calculated all "wasteful" numbers upto $n=10^9$ ? Quite a big search range for such a question. Could you post the picture showing the "pattern" ? How many "wasteful" numbers are below $10^9$ ? I upvoted, but even more context would be nice.

Comment: A very heuristic explanation for the oscillating density: A number that starts with a 1 is "long for its size", making it easier to find divisors that make it non-wasteful. A number that starts with a 9 is "short for its size" and therefore more likely to be wasteful as it already uses its digits very efficiently. So we expect the density of wasteful numbers near $n$ to fluctuate with the leading digit of $n$.

Comment: @Karl A very similar idea came into my mind as well ! A very good point !

Comment: The more I think about it the more I'm convinced that it is A122427, but I'm finding it hard to articulate why.

Comment: @Peter I have added graph for the density of wasteful numbers below $10^9$. There are $386000005$ wasteful numbers below $10^9$. The graph has a spike at every power of $10$.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha Did you defined this number as wasteful or this definition is given in some book or research paper?

Comment: @DQ Its my definition. If it already exists on some books than I am not aware of that

Comment: @NilotpalSinha Why do you think defining a wasteful number is important and what's your intuition behind it? How can it help in understanding more about numbers?

Comment: @DQ Unlike applied math, we should not worry about importance/utility of something in pure math. We do it for the joy of doing it.

Comment: @NilotpalSinha But still the definitions and theorems in pure math have strong intuitions and theoretical significance behind them. They explain concepts.

Comment: @lulu Your suspicion is right. Indeed every wasteful number n must be its own lexicographically greatest divisor. Proved in MO. I had added the link in the update to the question